# Dynamically changing the styles of controls

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, styles

I have created a screen (Screen1.xaml) that has few text boxes and dropdowns. Since the properties of all the text boxes are same, I have created a styles file(stylesheet.xaml) with the properties like width, height, Font size etc. like this

```
<Style x:Key="TextBox.Base" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlock.Base}">
<Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
</Style>
```

Now, I want to dynamically change the properties of the controls depending on some conditions. I want to acheive this doing something in the code-behind. Please help.

Comment: Is it important to apply a new Style resource, or will the VisualStateManager give you what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can pick a style and change it in code-behind. Depending on the way you have included it to your project there are several ways:

```
// the style defined in the app.xaml (you need a key)
Style globalStyle = Application.Current.Resources["Key"] as Style;

// the style defined for a control (you need its key)
UserControl control = ...
Style controlStyle = control.Resources["Key"] as Style;

// the current style of the control
Style currentStyle = control.Style;
```

Change the style like this:

```
style.SetValue(UserControl.FontSizeProperty, (float)10);
```

**Edit:**
As I read now, to change a style will only affect all controls that use it in WPF. In Silverlight, you might change the property for all controls :(